# How to create eCheck account type in paypal buyers sandbox account ? And, How to test it with ebay sandbox orders?

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-sandbox

We have paypal buyer sandbox & seller sandbox account. Also we have ebay buyer & seller sandbox account.

I checked one order from the ebay buyer account. So from that i get redirect to the paypal sandbox account. 
So there i got option to change account type. But there i did not get eCheck account type.
so I tried to create eCheck account in my paypal buyer account.

Please give full details to how to create eCheck account type in paypal buyer.
What things should i needs to do?

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox does not currently support the eCheck funding option. If you need to test the IPN data that will be sent in relation to these types of payments, you can use the IPN Simulator at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator.

Comment: Is this still a sandbox limitation?  This is not a sufficient solution for many developers such as myself who have an isolated dev environment that the PayPal servers can't access.  We need a way to test this in a truly sandboxed environment.